# Substitute [] by std::array

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to substitute `VECTOR_TYPE::*memberlist[sizeof...(SCALAR)]` by `std::array< ??? >`?

```
struct myVec
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

template < typename VECTOR_TYPE, typename SCALAR_TYPE, SCALAR_TYPE VECTOR_TYPE::*...SCALAR >
struct vector_template : VECTOR_TYPE
{
    SCALAR_TYPE & operator[]( size_t inx )
    {
        constexpr SCALAR_TYPE VECTOR_TYPE::*memberlist[sizeof...(SCALAR)]{ SCALAR... };
        return this->*(memberlist[inx]);
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector_template < myVec, double, &myVec::x, &myVec::y > vec;

    vec[0] = 0.0;
    vec[1] = 0.0;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. `T x[N]{args...}` can be replaced by `std::array<T,N> x{args...}`. In this case:

```
constexpr std::array<SCALAR_TYPE VECTOR_TYPE::*, sizeof...(SCALAR) >
    memberlist{{SCALAR...}};
```

Either way, it won't make any difference in this case.